# Angular 5 file download issue - index.html content shown

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to download a static file from a location within my code base. I'm using the following code to achieve this;

```
<div>
    <a [href]="'download/foo.csv'" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 20px;" target="_blank" download="Foo.csv">
        Download Import File Template
    </a>
</div>
```

However, when file Foo.csv is downloaded its content is same as the index.html file. Why is this happening?

Content of the index.html file is shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed|Source+Sans+Pro">
</head>
<body>
<div app></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/api/v2/config?plain=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="style.200453e6923c58c1d928.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="app.83fe6f9a0095f7b1bf2b.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open the network tab console  in google chrome and check whats the URL is hit when you click download.

Comment: @HameedSyed I already tried that but I don't see any URL end-point being hit.

Comment: It will be good if you can create a stackblitz ,you will get the solution quickly as it will be easy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping your CSV file in the `assets` folder which is where it is supposed to be kept ideally. And then try with this:

```
<div>
    <a 
    href="assets/sample.csv" 
    class="btn btn-default" 
    style="margin-left: 20px;" 
    target="_blank" 
    download="sample-file.csv">
        Download Import File Template
    </a>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/download-link-to-download-a-file?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

**PS:** The answer to why this works lies in the Building Configuration that is present in the `angular.json` file which I recommend you checking out.

Comment: Strange. Is it working for you on the Sample StackBlitz that I shared in my answer?